# normalized URL strips trailing slash

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

The implementation of `Location.normalize` in Angular 2 strips trailing slashes from URLs ([documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/Location-class.html)).  What is the reasoning behind this?  Can I go ahead and override this behaviour if I wish?  What are the potential consequences of doing so?  I would prefer that normalized URLs have a trailing slash, in part for consistency with the API exposed by the back-end part of my project ([reasoning](https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/)).

Edit: I see that there is a [commit against angular.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/3878be52f6d95fca4c386d4a5523f3c8fcb04270) which allows the configuring of this behaviour; is it likely that Angular 2 will support this in future too?  The documentation seems rather stipulative on the subject:

> A normalized URL is absolute from the URL host, includes the application's base href, and has no trailing slash.

Comment: This rubs up against my situation, actually... Using Angular 2 with ASP.NET Core host, the host (and Angular for that matter) see them as different URLs. If you think about it, "myapp.com/about" is a resource off the root. "myapp.com/about/" is a FOLDER with potentially other resources off it (like "myapp.com/about/worldheadquarters"). I think this is by design, and the Angular coders are following convention. Like you and presumably most end users, I see "/about" and "/about/" as the same location. But computers are more picky, and for good reason.

Comment: quite the opposite in fact -- I see `/about` and `/about/` as different resources; the former is a singular resource, and the latter is a collection.  But the most important reason why trailing slashes is important is to allow relative URLs to work properly for the API.  See, e.g., https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/why-trailing-slashes-on-uris-are-important/