# Angular2 keep/add trailing slash

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an issue with trailing slashes being removed by Angular2. I've setup my dotnet core application to add them, but they get removed as soon as the js get loaded in.

Is it even possible in Angular2?

(My client requires it, so no need to add a comment saying; don't use trailing slash).

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Should have added, this is running with Angular2-Universal, so upgrading the angular version is not that easy :(

Answer (score 1):

We have a website by Angular one, after we decided migrating to Angular4 Universal one of our problem was auto-removed trailing slash that efficacy on our site SEO, after many tries we found a hacky way for preventing this unvaluable action by same as below code(in app.module.ts file):

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location } from '@angular/common';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';


@Injectable()
export class UnstripTrailingSlashLocation extends Location {
  public static stripTrailingSlash(url: string): string {
    return url;
  }
}


Location.stripTrailingSlash = UnstripTrailingSlashLocation.stripTrailingSlash;

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe is a [problem faced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708191/normalized-url-strips-trailing-slash#comment66265780_38708191) by .Net Devs

The commit with this fix in the `2.3.0-beta.1` version of angular. Try changing your angular version and see if the problem is fixed.

[fix: support trailing slash in basePath](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/0d1f3c3)

**Alternatively**

Have you tried this? This seems to do the trick on my machine

In app.routing.ts:

`{ path: 'link/.', component: MyComponent },`

A hyperlink:

```
<li class="nav-item" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">
        <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/link/.']">MyComponent</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: This seems to be only for the basePath. If I go to "/articles/article-1/", it strips it to "articles/article-1" - But I need, and want, it to keep the trailing slash.

Comment: add a period after the slash